# How to uniform ui-block heights within ui-grid

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I am striping alternate rows of ui-blocks in jQuery Mobile. There are three columns, but when a cell on a row contains a different number of wrapped lines than its neighbor the background color only fills in the lines that are occupied.

For example ui-block-a (1 line), ui-block-b (2 lines), ui-block-c (2 lines). If this were a striped row block b and c would show 2 lines of text with the background color. block A shows a blank line after the line of text to keep the heights consistent but unfortunately the background color for the stripe only shows on the first line for block-a.

Here is the CSS and the HTML

CSS

```
.stripe {
  background-color: #EAEAEA; 
}
```

HTML

```
<div data-role="content">   
    <div class=ui-grid-b>
      <div class=ui-block-a><strong>First Name</strong></div>
      <div class=ui-block-b><strong>Last Name</strong></div>
      <div class=ui-block-c><strong>Organization</strong></div>

      <div class="ui-block-a stripe">Allison</div>
      <div class="ui-block-b stripe">Akhnoukh</div>
      <div class="ui-block-c stripe">Education Consultant</div>

      <div class=ui-block-a>Kemi</div>
      <div class=ui-block-b>Akinsanya-Rose</div>
      <div class=ui-block-c>New York City Department of Education</div>      
    </div>
</div><!-- /content -->
```

Comment: Can you include your jQuery, and a [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.com) demo of the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Yea it's too bad there is no [row class](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#gridSystem), similar to what you would have in Bootstrap. With that being said, perhaps you can float another div as a wrapper around your block items like this:

```
<div class=ui-grid-b>
    <div style="float:left;width:100%">
      <div class=ui-block-a><strong>First Name</strong></div>
      <div class=ui-block-b><strong>Last Name</strong></div>
      <div class=ui-block-c><strong>Organization</strong></div>
    </div>

    <div style="float:left;width:100%">
      <div class="ui-block-a">Allison</div>
      <div class="ui-block-b">Akhnoukh</div>
      <div class="ui-block-c">Education Consultant</div>
    </div>

    <div class="stripe" style="float:left;width:100%">
      <div class=ui-block-a>Kemi</div>
      <div class=ui-block-b>Akinsanya-Rose</div>
      <div class=ui-block-c>New York City Department of Education</div>      
    </div>
</div>
```

Example Fiddle [found here](http://jsfiddle.net/scottiemc7/Xmx6E/3/)